# My inbox messages copying to sent folder with weird address

Tags: gmail

This is a photo that is from my sent box that copied from my inbox.  Notice the goofy address:

[[image: messages][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIGvyl.png)

How do I fix this?

Comment: The screenshot is there now.

Comment: The screenshot is from a mobile app, not from the Gmail web app. What app are you using? Are these emails on the  Sent view on https://gmail.com or only  on your mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like messages you or your mail application have marked as spam / junk messages are being moved to your Sent folder. In the settings for your account, you can set it up for how you want spam or junk messages handled -- where you want spam or junk messages to go to. Check your settings to make sure they haven't been set to go to your Sent folder instead of your Spam folder. You usually have three options.

1. Send the message directly to the Trash folder.
2. Send it to a Junk or Spam folder so you can review it to make sure it is spam before your send it to Trash.
3. Send it to some other folder name you want it to go to.